# var inside the function giving undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, console.log

update 1: why I am getting undefined

I am trying to earn js hoisting.
when I put it inside function I am getting undefined, but where as when I dont put any function I am getting output.
when I use let I am getting error
providing code snippet below

```js
var numOfBeers = 5;
    
function getMoreBeers() {
  console.log('I have this many beers: ' + numOfBeers); // undefined
    
  var numOfBeers = 25;
  return numOfBeers;
}
    
console.log('I now have this many beers: ' + getMoreBeers());
```

```
I have this many beers: undefined
I now have this many beers: 25
```

```js
console.log('I have this many beers: ' + numOfBeers);
    
var numOfBeers = 25;
```

```
VM336:2 I have this many beers: 25
```

```js
console.log('I have this many beers: ' + numOfBeers);

let numOfBeers = 25;
```

```
VM333:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'numOfBeers' has already been declared
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var) - See the "Hoisting" discussion, which is an example almost identical to yours.

Comment: Your variable is undefined until it is assigned a value.

Comment: You are declaring a new version of the variable inside your function, the declaration of which is hoisted above the `console.log` call, but your assignment is after. The equivalent of `function getMoreBeers() { var numOfBeers; console.log(...); numOfBeers = 25; }`. If you remove the decaration inside the function and just keep the assignment, then the `var` declared in the global scope will be used.

Comment: also see: [How JS hoisting works within functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432620/how-js-hoisting-works-within-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Because you [shadowed](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-variable-shadowing-in-javascript) the outer variable by declaring an internal one of the same name.

```js
var numOfBeers = 5;
    
function getMoreBeers() {
  console.log('I have this many beers: ' + numOfBeers); // undefined
    
  var numOfBeers = 25; // Because you defined a local var here!
  return numOfBeers;
}
    
console.log('I now have this many beers: ' + getMoreBeers());
```

Here is the same code as above, but with the variable "hoisted":

```js
var numOfBeers = 5;
    
function getMoreBeers() {
  var numOfBeers; // Because you defined a local var here!

  console.log('I have this many beers: ' + numOfBeers); // undefined
    
  numOfBeers = 25; // Now we assign...
  return numOfBeers;
}
    
console.log('I now have this many beers: ' + getMoreBeers());
```

Change the internal name:

```js
var numOfBeers = 5;
    
function getMoreBeers() {
  console.log('I have this many beers: ' + numOfBeers); // undefined
    
  var localNumOfBeers = 25; // Local var here!
  
  numOfBeers = localNumOfBeers; // Update the outer var
  
  return localNumOfBeers;
}
    
console.log('I now have this many beers: ' + getMoreBeers());
```

This will produced instead:

```
I have this many beers: 5
I now have this many beers: 25
```

Comment: Hey but within the function why its not printing 25, since below statement we are using --->   numOfBeers = localNumOfBeers; // Update the outer var

Comment: It's got nothing to do with shadowing just hoisting, isn't it?. Remove the outer variable and the behavior is the same. You should explain that with hoisting, it's as if a new statement `var localNumOfBeers;` is added at the top of the function (hoisted) and declares the variable at the beginning of the function as undefined