# Why does the second code snippet give an error but the first one runs fine for JS?

Tags: javascript, scope, lexical-scope

I am learning about Lexical Environments in JavaScript and came across this error.
Code snippet with error:

```js
let x = 1;

function func() {
  console.log(x); 
  let x = 2;
}

func();
```

But this code runs correctly:

```js
let x = 1;

function func() {
  console.log(x);
}

func(); //logs out 1
```

I expected the first code snippet to log the value 1, and then give the error that x has already been declared but instead it gives me a reference error for the console.log(x) section.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432620/how-js-hoisting-works-within-functions

Comment: In your examples, the first errors and the second actually logs 1, rather than 2.

Comment: because javascript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to hoisting in JavaScript. The let keyword is block-scoped and is hoisted to the top of the block but not initialized. In the first code snippet, console.log(x) is encountering the variable x before it is declared and initialized within the block, resulting in a ReferenceError. In the second code snippet, the variable x is declared and initialized before the console.log(x) statement, avoiding the error.

```
let x = 1;
function func() {
  let x = 2;
  console.log(x);
}
func();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet, the error occurs because JavaScript does not allow accessing a `let` variable before it's declared within the same block. In `func()`, you're trying to use `x` before its declaration with `let`, which causes an error. In the second snippet, there's no `let` declaration of `x` inside `func`, so the outer `x` is used without any issue.

Comment: Shouldn't the JS engine check if an x exists in the outer scope (the x defined within the global scope) and use that value ?